# Custom fill sequence excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I want to do a custom fill sequence in Excel that i can drag. For the life of me i can't find the answer to this.

Two desired outcomes:

```
A1=B1,
A2=B7,
A3=B14,
A4=B21,
```

But what i really like is:

```
Sheet2!C1=Sheet1!C1:C6,
Sheet2!C2=Sheet1!C7:C13,
Sheet2!C3=Sheet1!C14:20,
and so on
```

This one might be harder,

As you may have guessed. Sheet 1 is daily totals, Sheet 2 is weekly and Sheet 3 is Monthly.

Comment: Can you clarify what you "really" want?  Sheet1!C1:C6 is a range, which you can't put in a single cell.  Are you talking about something like the sum of the cells in that range?

Comment: Have you tried messing around with `mod`?

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you are trying to accomplish in the 2nd scenario... but for the first one this will work:

```
A1: =B1
A2: =INDIRECT("B" & ROW(A1) - 1 * 7)
```

Select **only A2** when you drag the formula down.

Note that the function is volatile, so for larger datasets your sheet is going to get resource intensive.